# 400 Bad Request With urllib2 for POST

Tags: python, rest, http-post, urllib2, urllib

I am struggling from 2 days with a post request to be made only using urllib & urllib2. I have limitations in using curl or requests library, as the machine I would need to deploy my code doesn't support any of these.

The post call would be accompanied with a Header and json Body. I am able to make any get call, but POST with Data & Header throws 400 bad requests. Tried and applied all the options available in google/stackoverflow, but nothing solved!

Below is the sample code:--

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'https://1.2.3.4/rest/v1/path'
headers = {'X-Auth-Token': '123456789sksksksk111',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
body = {'Action': 'myaction',
        'PressType': 'Format1', 'Target': '/abc/def'}
data = urllib.urlencode(body)
request = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request, data)
```

And on setting debug handler, below is the format of the request that can be traced:--

```
send: 'POST /rest/v1/path HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nContent-Length: 52\r\nHost: 1.2.3.4\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/2.7\r\nConnection: close\r\nX-Auth-Token: 123456789sksksksk111\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n\r\nAction=myaction&PressType=Format1&Target=%2Fabc%2Fdef'

reply: 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n'
```

Please note, the same post request works perfectly fine with any REST client and with Requests library. In the debug handler output, if we see, the json structure is Content-Type: `application/json\r\n\r\nAction=myaction&PressType=Format1&Target=%2Fabc%2Fdef`, can that be a problem!

Comment: do u specifically want to use urllib or should I use request module also ?

Comment: @akashkarothiya:- quote from the question:- " I have limitations in using curl or requests library" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dump the json instead of encoding it. I was facing the same and got solved with it!

Remove `data = urllib.urlencode(body)` and use `urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(data))`

That should solve.

Comment: Thanks much. It at least solved the format 400 bad request issue. :)